# Clear POST in web page

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a small python/django web site and I'm using a html form POST some information, annoyingly however this information is stored in POST so when a user refreshes in say IE/chrome they get that warning message about the page containing POST data. How do I clear the POST data after it has been processed so a user can refresh and not see this warning message?

Also I have some logic as follows that detects a POST

```
 if request.method == "POST":
     do something
```

Select all
Open in new window

This is fine when I actually post the form, but when I refresh the page it also detects the POST and does the logic that I now dont want to do.
How can I solve this also??

Thanks

Comment: refreshing = sending the same POST request on the clientside, users will get the message regardless of what you do in django, if you send the request using AJAX or redirect them after response to another page it won't happen

Comment: To prevent re-posting often a **redirect** is done, as this goes back to the browser saying jump to ... .

Answer (score 0):

After form is validated and it is valid. Then do the redirect to some other page e.g. a success page or redirect to the same view. The redirection will avoid `Double Form Submition problem`. Read more about it [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post).

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpResponseRedirect` when you return the response for POST request. This is explained in [tutorial 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04) as

*After incrementing the choice count, the code returns an HttpResponseRedirect rather than a normal HttpResponse. HttpResponseRedirect takes a single argument: the URL to which the user will be redirected (see the following point for how we construct the URL in this case).*

*As the Python comment above points out, you should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn't specific to Django; it's just good Web development practice.*

Answer (score 0):

As Rohan said, you should use `HttpResponseRedirect`. But also you can use a shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do smth
        return redirect('/page-with-form/')
```